# How to edit the table created in IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have been searching for nearly 2 days but couldn't find an answer, so let me ask here.

I just started using ASP.NET MVC 5. I have managed to extend the default ApplicationUser : IdentityUser class, so now it stores additional information on the users. One of the extended features was storing which organisation a user belongs to. An organisation can have multiple users. In the application, I want to be able to add users to any organisation. I also want to be able to manage organisations directly. Here is my model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string DWId { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    //...
}
```

After the migration, the EF created a separate table for Organisations. So far, so good.

Now, I want to be able to view and add/remove/delete organisations from Organisations table. For that I have created a controller. However, inside the controller, I am not able to reference the Organisations table so I could pass it as a model to the view. Here is what I have in mind, but failing to do:

```
public ActionResult Organisation()
{
    ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    var model = _db.Organisations.ToList(); //this does not work

    return View(model);
}
```

When I tried building it, it says

> 'TrendfinderMVC.Models.ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Organisations' and no extension method 'Organisations'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'TrendfinderMVC.Models.ApplicationDbContext' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In fact, as I began typing '_db.', the IntelliSense did not even show anything related to Organisations in the list. How would I get the list of all organisations currently? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `var model = _db.Organisations.ToList(); //this does not work`  What happens instead?

Comment: @damienc88, I've just edited the original message (the end part) to include what happened when I tried to build it.

Comment: You should spellcheck your code:  `organization`

Comment: Dan-o, certain countries accept organisation as the correct spelling. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/organisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have declared your set of Organisations in your `ApplicationDbContext` class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection"){}

    public DbSet<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps @damienc88, it solves the issue. I was under the impression that they are automatically created.